# How can I show the div when its display none?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

when i click the Cross (X) btn in div its should we close and when I click the Rundown List its show me div example:-
when I click the Business news Cross btn its close the div but when i click the rundown List business news its show me business new
i have try but i when i click the cross btn is again not open the div

Code:-.

Parent component

```
const LeftNav = () => {
return (

            <div className="allDivs">
                {item.map((items, index) => {
                    //   console.log(item)

                    return (
                        <div key={index} >
                            <TabHeader item={items} index={index}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

 </div >
    )
}
export default LeftNav;
```

Child componentL;-

```
    export default function TabHeader({ item, index }) {
   const [Close, setClose] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("activeFOCUS", activeFOCUS);
        setShow(ontoggle);
    }, [])
        return (
                <Fragment>
                    <div id="CLOSEDIV" style={Close === true ? { display: "none" } : { display: "block" }}>
                        <div className="TableText" onClick={(e) => { handleOnClick(e, Delete.val) }}>
                            <div id="SHOW">{Delete.val}</div>
                        </div>
     
    //cross btn
                    <div className="CloseIcon" id="CloseBtn"><FaRegTimesCircle
                        style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "20px", height: "20px", alignItems: "right" }}
                        onClick={(e) => { handleToggle(e, index, Delete.val) }} /></div>
                </div>
        </div>
         </Fragment >
    
        )
    }
```

please help....

Answer (score 0):

Try using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` instead of `display: none`